# How to save user updated chart.js data?

Tags: javascript, authentication, local-storage, chart.js, chart.js2

I have created a graph that updates using buttons in chart.js . How would I go about saving this data so that it is persistent after a refresh? I am planning on making a basic user system so that each individual has a balance that is taken out of or added to when they buy or sell. (doesn't need to be extremely secure just a basic identification system).

**Link to my code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/JB123/bogejacf/

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      title: {
        text: "Stock"
      },
      data: [{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: [{
            y: 100
          },
          {
            y: 90
          },
          {
            y: 80
          },
          {
            y: 70
          }
        ]
      }]
    });
    chart.render();

    $("#buy").click(function() {

      var length = chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.length;
      chart.options.title.text = "New DataPoint Added at the end";
      chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push({
        y: (chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[length - 1].y) + (chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[length - 1].y) / 50
      });
      chart.render();

    });

    $("#sell").click(function() {

      var lastpoint = chart
      var length = chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.length;
      chart.options.title.text = "New DataPoint Added at the end";
      chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push({
        y: (chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[length - 1].y) - (chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[length - 1].y) / 50
      });
      chart.render();

    });


  }
```

Comment: Your question can be boiled down to "how do I persist an array?" Just use `localStorage`. You already tagged your question with this, so I'm wondering where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Do you want the data to persist just for the current session or across multiple sessions ?

Comment: @PaW across multiple sessions.

Comment: @ChrisG How people effect the data should apply to all users but not effect their balance. In addition I have not found a successful way of storing the chart.js data in localStorage. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: If you want it to effect all users, the data needs to be sent to the server. Which backend are you using right now? Do you want the effect to be visible in real time? Because now we're talking about a client-server approach and possibly socket.io

Comment: @ChrisG I had been thinking about that. Originally this was more of a toy project and now I wish to expand it. Currently I am only running my code either locally or on jsfiddle.

Comment: If you want to persist the data locally (i.e. within the browser) you have the option of using either localStorage or IndexedDB. However, these options are not viable if the user has turned on "private/incognito mode" or clears the settings after every session. In such cases, the only reliable option would be to persist the data on a server.

Comment: @PaW That's another reason why I was hesitant to a localStorage approach. I think a server side approach would be best. I am still rather new to server side javascript. How would I go about this and how can I improve in my knowledge of the subject. I understand the basic concepts but I am a self taught programmer. Perhaps this is better as a separate question.

Comment: This is a tough one to answer since there are literally tons of options out there. Since you will be saving the data from the client, you may want to go with a storage solution that provides a REST based api. Since you are currently in the exploratory phase, you can try the free MongoDB option offered by mLab (https://mlab.com/plans/pricing/#plan-type=sandbox) to get a better understanding of the basics. There are other "trial" options available from Amazon, Google, Microsoft, etc. that you can also explore based on your needs. Hope that helps.

Comment: You may find the information on "Database as a service" in this wikipedia article useful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_database#Vendors